# Why does this code wrap function calls with Object(fn)(...)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitch

Twitch.tv has deployed, minified production code that looks like this:

```
var SomeFunctions = {
    func: function(arg) {
        /* ... */
        return true;
    },
    /* ... */
};
/* ... */
function otherCode() {
    /* ... */
    var a = 3;
    if (Object(SomeFunctions.func)(a)) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Obviously this is inserted by a minifier / transpiler, but why? What's the benefit of this code pattern?

It certainly doesn't protect you from TypeErrors:

```
>> Object(undefined)(3)
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

This pattern occurs more than 1,800 times in a single JS file.

For completeness, here is a screenshot of the (formatted) code:

[image: Screenshot of some code. The relevant portion is "Object(S.j)(t.props.targetLogin)".]